# DSpace New Embargo OAI Interface after Embargo end

Tags: dspace, oai

We are currently using DSpace 4.1 and I have a question concerning the visibility of an item at the OAI Interface after the Embargo ended.

The request at the OAI interface contains a date range (like: from 01.09.2014 until now). I didn't find a change of the last_modified date in the database when an embargo ends. This means that the item is not recognized as a changed item => not updated in the Solr OAI core => not visible visible with the date range query.

Is this true? Because with the old embargo system the last_modified changed after the EmbargoLifter was executed and the item would show ant the OAI interface.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have never tested for this issue.  If your testing shows this to be true, I suggest filing a DSpace bug report.  I wonder if a script could be written to look for expired embargos and force an update of the discovery record.

Comment: In this case I will further investigate the issue and file a bug report if necessary.